# Concatenating Multiple Columns in SQL Using CONCAT

Tags: sql

I'm currently working on a SQL query where I need to concatenate values from multiple columns into a single string. The table structure involves columns like *first_name*, *last_name*, and *designation*. I want to create a new column that combines these values with a specific separator.

Here's my attempt using the `CONCAT` function:

sql :

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name, ' - ', designation) AS full_info
FROM employee_table
```

While this works, I'm wondering if there's a more elegant or efficient way to achieve this, especially when dealing with a large dataset.

Additionally, I would like to handle cases where some values might be *NULL* without resulting in unexpected behavior. How can I modify the query to gracefully handle *NULL* values during concatenation?
Any insights or alternative approaches to concatenate columns using `CONCAT` in SQL would be appreciated!

While this works, I'm wondering if there's a more elegant or efficient way to achieve this, especially when dealing with a large dataset

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: To cater for nulls https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce if you are doing this a lot consider https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: What about JSON?

Comment: You may use [concat_ws](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function for that. It is implemented in most DBMS (Oracle is a notable exception).

Answer (score 1):

For MSSQL Server:

```
  CONCAT_WS('Delimiter',val1,val2, etc..)
```

Will let you set your delimiter so you don't have to specify it more that once, but you can only use that delimiter.

As for dealing with **NULL** you can use **ISNULL()** for each paramater in your **CONCAT_WS()** or **COALESCE()** difference is that **COALESCE()** Lets you specify more than 1 column to check.

Afterwards, you could use the **REPLACE()** function to remove cases in your string where the default for the **NULL** value was returned if you desire that.

You're query might look something like:

```
 WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',ISNULL(val1,'Empty'),ISNULL(val2,'Empty'),ISNULL(val3,'Empty')) as 'MyString'
    FROM MyTable
)
 SELECT REPLACE(MyString,'-Empty','') as 'Result' FROM CTE
```

You could do it all in one step, but this is just for readability.